# Is Windows network printing going to start failing again?

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, windows-update, network-printer

Last year, I helped some folks with Windows-machine networks with printing issues, figuring out (thanks to the magic of the interwebz) that Microsoft updates broke network printing somehow. Avoiding/uninstalling the updates worked around the issue.

Now, I'm reading this: [MS warns new Windows updates may break printing](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-warns-that-new-windows-updates-may-break-printing/).

My questions...

- Will this affect regular (= non-Server) Windows users? Specifically, Windows 10 users?
- MS says that

  > The affected devices are smart card authenticating printers, scanners, and multifunction devices that don't support either Diffie-Hellman (DH) for key-exchange during PKINIT Kerberos authentication or don't advertise support for des-ede3-cbc ('triple DES') during the Kerberos AS request

  how can I tell whether my printer falls into this category? I never purchased or installed a smart cards separately from the printer itself, but maybe it has a smart card internally?

Comment: It depended in part the last time on which printer(s) is was. Not all printers failed the last time. I suggest updating and see where you are and go from there. You likely will not learn much by not updating.

Answer (score 0):

After reading that webpage, it is my understanding that printers will only fail if they use smartcard authentication, and the printerdrivers used are not signed correctly.

This means that only a very small subset of printers is going to be affected, and those printers are business printers that quite likely will have support by the manufacturer unless they are very old and the manufacturer stopped supporting them a long time ago.

These printers will have the ability to use a smartcard to manage printer authentication. In such cases, you send the printjob to the printer, the printer will queue your jobs for you and once you are at the printer, you can insert your smartcard to authenticate to the printer that it is you, and it will start printing your prints for you, ensuring that no one else gets your prints.

As I understand it, if you have such printer but not use the smartcard authentication method at all, you would not be affected, but the fact that you say: I don't know if my printer has it, maybe internally? Then it is extremely likely, that your printer simply doesn't have a smartcard authentication option.

Do note, this form of secure printing does not rely on just smartcards. I've also seen secure printing by the use of userid+pincode authentication.